# Parametros opcionales en store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un *stored procedure* que requiere de 2 parámetros.

```
@Estatus nchar(1), @Id smallint

Select ...
where S.Estatus=@Estatus and S.Id=@Id
```

Mi problemática es que, cuando requiero llamarlo en mi backend, funciona diferente para dos tipos de usuarios, es decir para el usuario tipo1

```c#
 var item = _context.MyClass.FromSqlRaw($"sp_MyStoreProcedure "+estatus+", " + id + "").ToList();
```

Y para el usuario tipo2 solo requiero enviar el parámetro @Estatus y quiero que me devuelva todos los Id, pero si no le especifico el Id me tira error, y no le puedo poner uno especifico porque necesito todos y no lo puedo inicializar en el store procedure como null porque no me regresaría ninguno.

```c#
 var item = _context.MyClass.FromSqlRaw($"sp_MyStoreProcedure "+estatus+"").ToList();
```

¿Existe una forma de solucionar esto? o ¿debería crear un *stored procedure* para cada tipo de usuario? o ¿existe alguna manera de quitarle el `where` y especificarlo yo de manera manual en mi backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a que un procedimiento puedes obviar enviarle un parámetro.

En el siguiente ejemplo puedes ver como hacerlo, asignando un valor por defecto al @Id

```
Create procedure spMiSP 
@Estatus nchar(1)
, @Id smallint = -1
as

IF(@id = -1)
   begin
     select * from MiTabla where Estatus = @Estatus
   end
else
   begin
     select * from MiTabla where Estatus = @Estatus and ID = @Id
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar el procedimiento almacenado con el segundo parámetro con un valor por defecto. Esto permite llamarlo sin especificar ningún valor.

Mi recomendación es, en este caso, que el valor por defecto sea `null`, y puedes escribir una consulta que devuelva todos los `id`s cuando este parámetro tenga dicho valor, por ejemplo:

```
create procedure buscarPorStatusID(@Estatus nchar(1), @Id smallint = null)
as
begin
  select *
    from MiTabla
   where MiTabla.Estatus = @Estatus
     and (@Id is null or MiTabla.Id = @Id);
end
go
```

Esto permitiría utilizar las sentencias de llamado con uno o dos parámetros, tal como deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que pasar siempre los dos parámetros para el usuario tipo2 envias el parámetro @Estatus con el valor que le corresponde y @Id cuando lo mandas NULL utilizas el siguiente código

begin
select * from MiTabla
where Estatus = @Estatus
and ID      = ISNULL(@Id,ID)
end